# Parallax background in with depth in Phaser 3

Tags: phaser, typescript

I'm working on a 2D space shooter type of game in typescript using [Phaser 3](https://phaser.io/phaser3) and am trying to get a parallax background with different depths going. But I'm having trouble getting the math right.

You can see my work in progress here: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pea9yVbTD64](https://phaser.io/phaser3)

As stated in the video everything works if the players x and y are positive, but breaks when they are negative, and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Or perhaps there is a better way to accomplish this?

What I'm doing is randomly generating out a bunch of the Sprites, storing them in an `Array`, and then updating their position with this code.

- **_Nebulas**: is an `Array<NebulaParticle>`.
- **p.distance**: is a number between 1 and 5 to signify how far away the sprite is and is used to make them move slower when they are
  furher away.
- **_Width** and **_Height** are both arbitrary numbers to signify how big the area is that the parallax should cover, in the video they are
  both set to 80.
- **OriginalOffsetX/Y** is the original random po﻿sition the Sprite was given.

(this line is here because the below code formatting wont work otherwise.)

```
public update(delta: number, playerx: number, playery: number) {
    console.log(playerx + ", " + playery );
    for (let i = 0; i < this._Nebulas.length; i++) {
        let p = this._Nebulas[i];          
        p._Sprite.x = (playerx + (this._Width / 2)) - (((playerx / p.distance) + p.OriginalOffsetX) % this._Width);
        p._Sprite.y = (playery + (this._Width / 2)) - (((playery / p.distance) + p.OriginalOffsetY) % this._Height);
    }
}

class NebulaParticle {
    public _Sprite: Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite;
    public OriginalOffsetX: number;
    public OriginalOffsetY: number;
    public distance: number;
}﻿
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a camera with the gameobject method [`setScrollFactor`](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Matter.Image.html#setScrollFactor__anchor). Setting 0 makes it fixed to the camera; setting a number between 0-1 will make it scroll at varying rates, which you can use to set up parallax scrolling layers.

See an example [here](https://labs.phaser.io/view.html?src=src%5Ccamera%5Cset%20scroll%20factor.js)

Comment: Thank you, but I can get this to work, the problem comes in when I want to loop around an object so that when it leaves the trailing edge it comes in on the leading one. That is I want the parallax background to be infinite and self looping in all directions forever.

Comment: In the example you linked the hotdog should come back in on the leading edge when it goes out of the screen view from being left behind, it's that part which I can't get right.